# How to add column in PySpark dataframe with String value + values from another column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Input dataframe: Origional dataframe

```
      class  id                            name
     System   0                          System
  Generator   1                        Coal_Gen
```

Expected output: new column 'Index' with value **"ST " + class value + "( id value )"**

```
    class    id                            name               Index
     System   0                          System        ST System(0)
  Generator   1                        Coal_Gen     ST Generator(1)
```

Comment: If the answer helped you to resolve the issue, take a moment to accept/upvote the answer to close the thread as resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`concat`** function in spark.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---------+---+--------+
#|    class| id|    name|
#+---------+---+--------+
#|   System|  0|  System|
#|Generator|  1|Coal_Gen|
#+---------+---+--------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("index",concat(lit("ST"),lit(" "), col("class"),lit("("),col("id"),lit(")"))).\
show()
#+---------+---+--------+---------------+
#|    class| id|    name|          index|
#+---------+---+--------+---------------+
#|   System|  0|  System|   ST System(0)|
#|Generator|  1|Coal_Gen|ST Generator(1)|
#+---------+---+--------+---------------+
```